# Перемещение элемента

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь создать обёртку для DOM, которая давала бы возможность перетаскивать любой элемент страницы с помощью мыши.

После загрузки страницы, при движении мыши на объекте document в два элемента страницы записываются случайные числа. После того, как вы переместите квадрат и снова будете перемещать мышь по document, то случайные числа уже не записываются в нужные элементы (что-то я с событиями намудрил, видимо), и теперь записываются только во время перетаскивания. В чём может быть проблема?

Ссылка на сам код: http://jsfiddle.net/6H48h/.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="fr.js"></script>
    <title>trouble</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<script>
    function mj(data) {
        if (typeof (data) != 'object') {
            if (!data) {
                data = document.body;
            } else {
                if (data.substr(0, 1) == '.') {
                    data = document.getElementsByClassName(data.substr(1, data.length));
                } else if (data.substr(0, 1) == '#') {
                    data = document.getElementById(data.substr(1, data.length));
                } else {
                    data = document;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!data.oper) {
            data.oper = new Operation(data);
        }
        return data.oper;
    }

    function Operation(data) {
        this.obj = data;
        this.arrLaunch = {
            onmousemove: [],
            onclick: [],
            onmousedown: [],
            onmouseup: []
        }
        return this;
    }

    //binders
    Operation.prototype = {
        mousemove: function (func) {
            var self = this;
            this.arrLaunch['onmousemove'].push(func);
            if (!this.obj.onmousemove) this.obj.onmousemove = function (e) {
                self.launch('onmousemove');
            };
        },
        click: function (func) {
            var self = this;
            this.arrLaunch['onclick'].push(func);
            if (!this.obj.onclick) this.obj.onclick = function (e) {
                self.launch('onclick');
            };
        },
        mousedown: function (func) {
            var self = this;
            this.arrLaunch['onmousedown'].push(func);
            if (!this.obj.onmousedown) this.obj.onmousedown = function (e) {
                self.launch('onmousedown');
            };
        },
        mouseup: function (func) {
            var self = this;
            this.arrLaunch['onmouseup'].push(func);
            if (!this.obj.onmouseup) this.obj.onmouseup = function (e) {
                self.launch('onmouseup');
            };
        },
        //setters
        launch: function (type) {
            for (var i = 0; i <= this.arrLaunch[type].length - 1; i++)
            this.arrLaunch[type][i]();
        },
        getCoords: function (elem) {
            var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
            var body = document.body;
            var docElem = document.documentElement;
            var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;
            var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft;
            var clientTop = docElem.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0;
            var clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;
            var top = box.top + scrollTop - clientTop;
            var left = box.left + scrollLeft - clientLeft;
            return {
                top: Math.round(top),
                left: Math.round(left)
            };
        },
        getEvent: function (e) {
            return e || window.event;
        },
        drag: function (data) {
            var drag = this.obj;

            var self = this;
            mj(drag).mousedown(function (e) {
                e = mj(drag).getEvent(e);
                var coords = mj(drag).getCoords(drag);
                var shiftX = e.pageX - coords.left;
                var shiftY = e.pageY - coords.top;
                mj(document).mousemove(function (e) {
                    e = mj(drag).getEvent(e);
                    drag.style.left = e.pageX - shiftX + 'px';
                    drag.style.top = e.pageY - shiftY + 'px';
                    drag.style.position = 'absolute';
                    if (data && data['opacity']) drag.style.opacity = data['opacity'].split(',')[0];
                    if (data && data['cursor']) drag.style.cursor = data['cursor'].split(',')[0];
                });
            });

            mj(drag).mouseup(function () {
                if (data && data['cursor']) drag.style.cursor = data['cursor'].split(',')[1];
                if (data && data['opacity']) drag.style.opacity = data['opacity'].split(',')[1];
                if (data && data['stop']) data['stop']();
                document.onmousemove = document.ondragstart = document.body.onselectstart = null;
            });
            drag.ondragstart = function () {
                return false;
            };
        }
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        mj(document).mousemove(function () {
            q.innerHTML = Math.random();
        });
        mj(document).mousemove(function () {
            w.innerHTML = Math.random();
        });
        mj('#drag').drag({
            opacity: '0.7,1',
            cursor: 'move,auto'
        });
    }
</script>

<body>
    <div id="q">0</div>
    <div id="w">0</div>
    <div id="drag" style="background-color: green; width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь [http://jsfiddle.net][1]

[1]:http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6H48h/

Comment: Многа букафф =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас обработчиков для document.onmousemove две штуки. один добавляется в window.onload второй в drag для дива. А на mouseup для дива вы убираете сразу оба:

```
document.onmousemove = null;
```

У вас не предусмотрено удаление одного ненужного обработчика, да и очистка методов идет неправильно. Если дальше будет еще один mj(document).mousemove, то уже будет три обработчика, дальше больше.

Судя по всему тут какой-то велосипед, сложно что-то советовать...

Comment: А как правильно очищать методы? Я так понимаю, что нужно кардинально менять структуру, можете посоветовать какие изменения нужно сделать?

Comment: У вас методы накапливаются в массиве, следовательно нужна какая-то функция очистки этого массива, но это мало относится к делу... Имхо, лучше будет не обработчики удалять у объектов, а выставлять какой-то глобальный для них флаг - действуют они или нет. на mousedown ставим флаг dragging=true, на mouseup - убираем dragging=false. а в обработчике mousemove проверяем тянем или нет...

Comment: Спасибо, попозже попробую :)

Answer (score 0):

Чем не устраивает [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) или [drag-js](http://docs.prototype-ui.com/docs/rc0/files/util/drag-js.html)?

Использование фреймворков облегчает жизнь.

Comment: Тем, что очень хочется попробовать обойтись без фреймворков.

Comment: А чем обосновано такое желание, если не секрет?

Comment: Просто интересно, как всё устроено изнутри) Хочется самому (пусть даже прибегая к чей-то помощи) написать что-то интересное.

Comment: Удачи в начинаниях! Главное не сломайтесь когда останется одна рутина, доведите задуманное до конца.